# MS-Access VBA Name Search

Tags: ms-access, vba

I need some help in VBA with MS-Access. I am not much of coder but was able to compile a membership database in access. In any event, ran into a problem with my member search: any members' name contains " ' " in both last and first name field, like "O'Conner", "O'Neil", etc., cannot be found by the search while everyone else's name are fine. Can someone please point me to the right direction? Here is the code:

```
Dim stDocName As String
stDocName = "MemberView"

Dim swhere As String

'Search by name
If Not IsNull(txtFullName) Then
Dim sFullName As String
Dim sLastName As String
Dim sFirstName As String
Dim icount As String

sFullName = txtFullName
sLastName = Left(sFullName, InStr(1, sFullName, ",") - 1)
sFirstName = LTrim(Mid(sFullName, InStr(1, sFullName, ",") + 1))

swhere = "[Last Name]='" & sLastName & "' and [First Name]='" & sFirstName & "'"

icount = DCount("[Last Name] and [First Name]", "Members", swhere)

If icount > 1 Then
MsgBox " " & icount & " found"
Else

End If

Else

End If
```

I hope this is something simple or so just some variables that I set wrong.

Many thanks!

Comment: Yes, the members does have [last name] and [first name] field.

Comment: Try to replace single [`'`] with double [`""`] and check what happens. `swhere = "[Last Name]=""" & sLastName & """ and [First Name]=""" & sFirstName & """"`

Comment: Maciej Los: Yes, that worked!!! Wow... It was that easy..?! Thanks a million...

Comment: You're very welcome. I'm getting to post it as an asnwer. It would be great if you'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very well known issue. Take a look here: http://allenbrowne.com/casu-17.html

Try to replace single [`'`] with double [`""`] and check what happens.

```
swhere = "[Last Name]=""" & sLastName & """ and [First Name]=""" & sFirstName & """"
```